# CSS Horizontal Menu has wrong x-position, how to put directly under parent menu?

Tags: css, menu, positioning

I'm trying to build a horizontal drop down menu with CSS. But the submenu appears either at the complete left of the site (when I set it to `position: absolute`) or to the very left of the menu (when set to `position: relative`). I want it to appear directly below the menu I hover on.

Here's my code:

```
/* div für Menü */
.menu{
 height: 35px;
 float: left; 
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 outline: 1px solid grey;
 background-color: #f6f6f6;
 font-size:100%;
}

/* UL Menü */
.menu ul{
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

/* Untermenü anzeigen bei Mouseover */
.menu ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
}

/* Hintergrund ändern bei Mouseover */
.menu ul li:hover{
 background-color: #005ea2;
}


/* Menü LI */
.menu ul li{
 display: inline;
 height: 35px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-top: 9px;
 padding-bottom: 9px;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 border-right: 1px dashed gray;
}

/* Letzter Eintrag ohne Rand */
.menu li:last-child{
 border: none;
}


.menu a{ 
 line-height: 250%;
 color: #333333;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}


/* UL Untermenü */
.menu ul li ul{
 display: none;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #f6f6f6;
 outline: 1px solid gray;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 200;
}


/* LI Untermenü */
.menu ul li ul li{
 height: 35px;
 display: block;
 line-height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 border: none;
 background-color: #f6f6f6;
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: in future, it's helpful if you can provide a demo of what you've got - http://jsfiddle.net is a good way of doing it as it makes it easy to edit and test, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add here

```
.menu ul li:hover{
    background-color: #005ea2;
}
```

a `position: relative;`.

This will establish a [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block) in order to be able to position stuff relative to it. After that you can just fiddle with different `top` and `left` values to get the exact desired result.

Also the `z-index` on `.menu ul li ul` is useless.

*On a separate note: Welcome to StackOverflow!*